# R: syntax of svychisq and summary on a svytable

Tags: r

I'm working on a "svydesigned" database and having trouble using svysq.

Here's what I tried which worked:

```
AxB<-svytable(~A+B, surveydesign, Ntotal=100)
AxB
svychisq(~A+B, surveydesign)
```

And what I would like to make work:

```
svychisq(AxB, surveydesign)
```

returns "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

```
svychisq(~AxB, surveydesign)
```

returns "Error in formula [[2]][[2]] : Object of type symbol is not subsettable"

```
summary(AxB)
```

returns the table and the chisq, but with integers in the table  (so only 0 and 1 since my values are in 0.xx format due to Ntotal=100)

What bugs me is that the help states that "sumary on svytable calls svychisq". I'm still new to R syntax and can't figure out how to make svychisq return a result using the table instead of typing again the whole formula I just used to create the table.

I'd also like to be able to see the decimals when usign "summary", is there a way? I tried to use digits=4 but nothing changed.

Thanks.

Comment: Why is this important?

Comment: For me, coding efficiency (I made short variable names here, but most of the time they are not, I'd rather use the table than type the formula again), and learning WHY some things that I thought would work do not work. I'm not just trying to use R one time, I want to understand how to make it work well and fast. It's about knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svychisq` expects a `formula` and a `svydesign` object as arguments. It is just the way it was created, you won't be able to feed it a `svytable` argument. You could work around by writing your own function:

```
FOO <- function(x){
  temp <- as.character(attr(x, "call"))[2:3]
  svychisq(as.formula(temp[1]), design = eval(parse(text = temp[2])))
}
```

You feed it a `svytable` object, it retrieves the call of the object and feeds it back to `svychisq`.

`FOO(AxB)` should work as expected.